# Errors when using the Corridor Designer tool from Arctoolbox

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, reclassify, error-010328

I am using the corridor Designer ArcToolbox for designing a habitat suitability model and I've got the following errors:

```
Error 010328: syntax at or near symbol SPACE
ERROR 010267; Syntax error in parsing grid expression
```

I´ve tried moving the files without spaces and number to the default file of ArcGis. Also carefully rewriting the `txt.files` for the reclass table. And nothing seems to work.

Comment: Can you provide some more information about what your input data is, and what the `corridor Designer ArcToolbox` is? Also, I added the raster tag to the question - I assume that's what you are using!